# ActiveMQ network connectors syntax

Tags: activemq-classic, connector

ActiveMQ documentation is not that clear, regarding, and not only, [network connector syntax](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html).

E.g. the documentation states that to create a static network of brokers, use the `static` protocol:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

If you wish to use `failover`, you can't use:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="failover:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

but

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:failover:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

as mentioned [here](https://blog.christianposta.com/activemq/from-inside-the-code-activemq-network-connectors/).

`masterslave` protocol doesn't seem to work in versions 5.10.2 and later.

What if you wish to set some properties, too?

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:failover:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)?useExponentialBackOff=false"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

will work, but if you try to add more than one in the `uri`:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:failover:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)?useExponentialBackOff=false&maxReconnectDelay=3000"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

your broker won't start.

How can you add more properties in the `uri`? I also tried `;` or `,` as a separator without luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From Matt Pavlovich's comment, in XML files you should use `&amp;` instead of `&`:

```
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="static:failover:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)?useExponentialBackOff=false&amp;maxReconnectDelay=3000"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

or

```
<networkConnectors>
   <networkConnector uri="masterslave:(tcp://<host1>:<port1>,tcp://<host2>:<port2>)?useExponentialBackOff=false&amp;maxReconnectDelay=3000"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

if you use one of the lastest versions of ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Network Connectors imply 'failover'. You shouldn't use the failover: uri at all. Posta's article is outdated.

Comment: This is not correct, at least for version 5.10.2. When you use `static:failover`, if it finds the first broker it won't attempt to connect to the second one etc., only if the first broker goes down. If you use `static` only, then it tries to connect to both servers.

Comment: Using the failover: in network connectors isn't recommended. It "works" in that you can achieve some of the behavior. However, the 'masterslave:' uri was provided specifically for network connectors to address the network connector needs vs client-side failover: uri.  5.10.2 is over 6 years old-- masterslave: was added later, but does support the same uri params as 'static'. Try 5.16.3 and share log output if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for your reply Matt, however, at the moment we are stuck with 5.10.2; once we upgrade to a later version we can try `masterlave`. Do you have an answer for the other part of the question, though, about the properties in the `uri`?

Comment: When using XML (not activemq.xml specific), you have to escape the '&' as '&amp;'. Additional params go ?foo=bar&amp;doh=ray&amp;me=fa&amps;so=la

Comment: Thank you Matt. That was it. I forgot about that in XML files. :)